# Time complexity of an algorithm with nested loops

Tags: algorithm, loops, time, time-complexity

I've read a ton of questions on here already about finding the time complexity of different algorithms which I THINK I understand until I go to apply it to the outer loop of an algorithm which states:

for i=1 step i←n∗i while i < n^4 do

I can post the full algorithm if necessary but I'd prefer not to as it is for a piece of homework that i'd like to otherwise complete by myself if possible.

I just can't figure out what the complexity of that loop is. I think its just 4 unless n=1 but I am blank as to how to express that formally. Its that or im totally wrong anyway!

Is anyone able to help with this?

Comment: i don't know how to express this formally but, indeed for every value of n, it loops exactly 3 times. for 2 => i becomes 2,4,8 then exits loop. for 3 i becomes 3,9,27 then exits loop etc..

Comment: Plus I itself which would make it four times I think? Except 1, where it wouldn't loop at all..

Comment: ah yes, i forgot 1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your loop into C (just to make sure I understand your pseudo code):

```
for (i=1; i < n^4; i = i * n ) {
...
}
```

The key question is what is `i` after `x`th iteration?  Answer: `i^x` (you can prove by induction).  So when `x` is 4, then `i` is `n^4` and the loop exits.  So it runs in 4 iterations and is constant time.

Comment: Thankyou! Definitely put me on the right track for the rest of the question too :)